# Does the Fourier transform of a non-strictly positive real kernel $\Phi(t)$ always generate entire function with complex zeros?

Tags: fourier-transform

Question (1) Does the Fourier transform of a non-strictly positive real kernel

$f(t)$ always generate an entire function $g(z)$ with complex zeros?

$$g(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) \exp(izt)dt=2\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t) \cos(zt)$$

where $f(t)$ is continuous.

The function $f(t)$ behaves like the function $f_0(t)$ below:

$$f_0(t)=(1-(1/4)t^2)\exp(-t^2)$$

$f_0(t)$ has one real zero at $t_0=2$. So $f_0(t)<0$ when $t_0<t<\infty$ and $f_0(t) > 0$ when $0 < t < t_0$. $f(t) \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If you internalize the contents of this [very nice recent Master's Thesis from UHawaii](http://math.hawaii.edu/home/theses/MA_2014_Hallum.pdf), (the author is Hallum) you shall be enlightened.